# SqlException: Invalid column name 'IdCountry'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy haciendo un proyecto, acabo de editar el índice y detalles en el controlador para poder ver los departamentos o ciudades que tiene cada país, también edito el details.cshtml, pero me arroja este error, si alguien me puede ayudar , Te lo agradezco.

"SqlException: Invalid column name 'IdCountry'."

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Countries
            .Include(c => c.Departments)
            .ToListAsync());
    }
```

Ahí es el error

Comment: Existe esa columna en la tabla?

Comment: Si claro, se llama Id

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! se llama id, pero alguien la esta buscando como IdCountry.. tal vez estas usando EF?

Comment: Si, esty usando el entity framework @gbianchi

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta tendria que tener ese tag, y el codigo involucrado de EF. Actualizaste tu EF? no estara buscando una columna con ese nombre? el tag css no tiene nada que ver aca...

Comment: @gbianchi cambiaré el tag, como actualio mi EF, que pena pero soy nuevo usando esta arquitectura ya que es para un proyecto de la universidad

Comment: Ni idea. pero si muestras tu clase tal vez alguien pueda ayudarte...

Comment: Tenemos que ver los modelos.

Comment: Muestra tus modelos para poder ayudarte, por experiencia debes verificar tus modelos y hacer referencia a una propiedad del tipo del modelo del cual estas haciendo referencia en la llave foranea

Comment: Si dices que el campo en la tabla se llama `id` porqué usas `idCountry`?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías asegurarte que tu clase "Countries" o "Departments" que tiene una columna llamada IdCountry, exista en BBDD.
Si lo que ocurre es que se llama de otra forma, puedes añadir un DataAnnotation [Column(string name)] sobre la propiedad que se llame diferente, para ajustar tu modelo a la BBDD.